# Can you get the itok value programmatically?

Tags: ajax, services, media

I appreciate the 7.20 security measure that requires a `itok` parameter for generating new images, but I need to expose that to Services / AJAX driven projects.

Can you get the image token programmatically so that JavaScript can build valid image urls for any size dynamically?

I would like to avoid `$conf['image_allow_insecure_derivatives'] = TRUE;` unless someone has a project to apply this same security measure on a user session level as opposed to per image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible to get the token via a custom ajax callback that returns:

```
$token_query = array(IMAGE_DERIVATIVE_TOKEN => image_style_path_token($style_name, $original_uri));
```

From a custom menu router path or services callback.

Comment: thanks @tenken!, i'll try this now. Do you know how much processing goes into the token generation? Would doing this for a 50 images in a loop be a problem?

Comment: 50 images shouldnt be a problem, it's 2015 now .... Now 50000000 images ... Then yes you may have a problem :)

Comment: fair enough. thanks! it all works fine. Q: do you know if the tokens change over time / have a lifetime?

Comment: You tell me: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_path_token/7

Comment: for those of your whom appreciate little details on a same answer's page: tokens are a static hash of the image uri, some config variables, and the style name being generated. it does not change with time, only per image and database.